# Streaming audio on Google TV

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, multimedia, google-tv

Does anyone know how to play streaming audio on Google TV device? `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView` can't do this.

Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

MediaPlayer should work. For the basic code for streaming with MediaPlayer, check out:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer

If you're having trouble getting MediaPayer to work with your audio, it might be a package or decoder compatibility issue. The Google TV supported media types can be found at:

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats

Comment: Thanks, its works for tables but Google TV does not support this audio format, so i want to find some extraneous solution like custom library etc.